# How can I share development of same Visual Studio 2010 project between 2 PCs?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, share, synchronization

I have two PCs physically in different locations, both of which have Visual Studio 2010 installed. Now I'm starting development of a project in VS2010, and I want to be able to work on the project from both locations.

Is there any quick way to share the project in both locations, so that I can work from either place, on the latest code available till then ?

Also, do note that at any given time, development will ONLY take place at one of the either locations, not both ..

Please note though that I dont want to set up an SVN server .. Looking for some other simpler approach ..

Comment: Why exactly don't you want to use SVN? What's so complicated about it?

Comment: @Marek: I'm just guessing, but it could be that Svn in itself is not the problematic part, but rather to have a server that is accessible from both locations.

Comment: @FredrikMörk You may be right but it is also possible that Ahmad thinks it's not worth to use SVN because of the size of the project. Whereas I use SVN even when I develop a small project, do it all by myself and use a single machine - for me it is indispensable to be able to revert the code to the previous version. Using SVN for small projects is also a great way to master the branching and merging skills.

Answer (score 2):

I often run in this situation. What I do is to host my projects in a free SVN Server and check it out and in as neded.
This one has a free SVN service:
https://www.assembla.com/

Answer (score 2):

Set up an account at [github](https://github.com/), [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/) or similar. Then you don't need to set up your own server. One other option, if you are really the only developer, is to use a [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com) folder or something like that.